Remember apps' maximized window sizes on 24.04
Since upgrading to 24.04, several applications (e.g., Firefox, Audacity, Signal, others) do not remember maximized window sizes on relaunching and start with annoyingly sized and positioned windows instead. I am using 24.04.1 and Gnome on X.
How to force apps to remember maximized window sizes on launch?
Ideally solutions will apply system-wide, rather that rely on app-by-app solutions, and will ideally preserve memory of window sizes for all apps whether maximized or not.



Note: I already know keyboard shortcuts for window resizing and maximization: acceptable answers will not include some form of 'you can just maximize window sizes yourself'.

I don't have solution for now (having the same issue), but have found references to go down the rabbit hole:

older gnome bug, fixed in gnome 44
regression in mutter 46

What version of DE are you running, 46? Does your window also appear maximized for a split second (e.g. reopening Discord/Spotify/other from tray) and then getting immediately resized to a windowed mode? Does it also happen on wayland?

@Tooster I do not use Wayland. I am using Gnome 46 on Xorg.
